# A Geometry Problem from Indian RMO(Regional Mathematical Olympiad) 2016.

Tags: geometry, contest-math

Let $ABC$ be a triangle with centroid $G$. Let the circumcircle of triangle
$AGB$ intersect the line $BC$ in $X$ different from $B$; and the circumcircle of
triangle $AGC$ intersect the line $BC$ in $Y$ different from $C$. Prove that $G$ is
the centroid of triangle $AXY$.
I successfully solves this problem by assuming that $X$ lies between points $D$ and $B$ and $Y$ lies between points $D$ and $C$, Where $D$ is the foot of median from $A$ to $BC$.
**Is it necessarily true that $X$ lies Between $B$ and $D$?**

My Thoughts:
X cant't coincide with D because a circle can't pass through 3 colinear points (which can be proved easily).
I think x can't lie beyond D (I can't prove this right now but I think convexity may be involved).

Comment: Your thoughts, please....

Comment: What does centroid mean?

Comment: Centroid is the intersection point of Three medians in a triangle.

Comment: A fallout is : P of median AP is common midpoint of $BC,XY$.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple to brute-force:
[image]

$$ DG\cdot DA = DX\cdot DB = DX\cdot \frac{a}{2} = \frac{m_a^2}{3} = \frac{2b^2+2c^2-a^2}{12} \tag{1}$$
$$ DX = \frac{2b^2+2c^2-a^2}{6a} = DY \tag{2}$$
and by trilinear/baricentric coordinates $X,G$ and the midpoint of $AY$ are collinear. Similarly, $Y,G$ and the midpoint of $AX$ are collinear, proving the claim. In a simpler way: $AD$ is a median of $AXY$ and $\frac{AG}{GD}=2$, hence $G$ is the centroid of $AXY$.

Comment: Is it necessarily true that X lies Between B and D?

Comment: @ShubhashishChauhan: of course, $D$ is external to both $\Gamma_{ABG}$ and $\Gamma_{ACG}$, hence it has a positive power. It follows that $D$ cannot be enclosed by $\Gamma_{ABG}$ or $\Gamma_{ACG}$. $DG\cdot DA = DX\cdot DB$ gives that $X$ lies to the left of $D$, but $B$ might lie between $X$ and $D$.

Comment: how do we prove that D is External to $ΓABG$ and $ΓACG$

Comment: @ShubhashishChauhan: $\frac{AG}{GD}=2$ and $AG$ is a chord of both circles.